# How does warden get the current user from the rack session?

Tags: ruby, devise, warden

After the user has logged in (`ENV['warden'].authenticate!`'d) once, how does `warden` know this? I can not find anything in the cookie except for the `rack.session` value - I couldn't figure this out from the documentation or code.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? `env['rack.session']` contains the session for this specific user, and contains a `warden.user.key` or something...

Comment: @mhutter But where is that stored on the server? It seems to be Marshalled here (https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/cookie.rb) but I can't find where it's being stored. There seems to be two options: Memcached and Pooled, but can't find which one is the default, and which is used when. I do know that it persists after server shutdown, so memcached?

Comment: Are you sure it persists over restarts? The default is `Pool`, which stores data in a `Hash`: https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/session/pool.rb#L33

Comment: I am sure it persists after I restart the server.

Comment: Fun stuff... so the question is, how does rack persist sessions